# How to prevent duplicate bind mounts?

Tags: mount, fstab, automount, nfs

My fstab contains this:

```
192.168.0.8:/mnt/HD/HD_a2 /media/storage nfs rw,user,auto,hard,intr 0 0
/media/nas/Music /home/benubird/Music none bind,user,auto 0 0
```

If I run `mount /media/nas` twice, the second one fails with the message:

```
mount.nfs: /media/nas is busy or already mounted
```

which is correct behaviour. However, if I call mount on the bound folder twice, it mounts it twice!

The same thing occurs if I run `mount -a`.

How do I tell fstab to only mount the folder once? I don't know what the effect of mounting the same directory twice will be, but I imagine it's probably not good.

I've thought of writing a shell script to call `mount -l` to check if the folder is mounted, then only mount it if not, but it seems weird to me that the mount command would not already have this option.

So, specific questions:

· Why can mount detect that a non-bind mount is already mounted, but it can't detect that a bind mount is, even though after binding twice it shows up twice in `mount -l`?

· How do I tell `etc/fstab` to only mount if not already mounted?

· How do I tell the mount command, to not mount if already mounted?

(I'm using ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS)

Comment: It could be because it's user-specific.  What happens if you change `user` into `users`and reboot?

Answer (score 4):

You are simply not supposed to call mount -a unless you are init script or some other system program. Why do you need this?

but yes, you can test it in shell script

```
mountpoint -q /home/benubird/Music && echo is mounted || echo not mounted
```

however it does not work very well with bind mounts, sou you can grep /proc/mounts instead:

```
function is_mounted() {
    dir=$(echo "$1" | sed -e 's/\/\/*/\//g; s/\/$//g;')
    cut -d ' ' -f 2 /proc/mounts  | grep "^$dir$" >/dev/null
}
```